# Are function calls in javascript always a method

Tags: javascript, function, methods, global-variables

So Douglas Crockford taught us a lot about js. In particular that there are 4 ways of using functions

- Function Application

```
function f() {}
f();
```

- Method Invocation

```
var obj = {f: function (){}};
obj.f();
```

- Apply Pattern

```
var obj = {};
function f(){}
f.apply(obj);
```

- Constructor Call

```
function Person(){}
new Person();
```

My question since the this parameter when using the Function application is the global object. Isn't it effectivly just a special Method Inovcation.

for example

```
function f(){}
this.f(); // acts exactly like calling f();
```

It seems there are really only 3 patterns. Function Application doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems there are really only 3 patterns. Function Application doesn't actually exist.

It does, because `f();` uses the default `this` even if `this` in the context where you run it isn't the default `this`.

E.g.:

```
var global = this;
var obj = {
    method: function() {
        console.log(this === global);     // false
        f();

        function f() {
            console.log(this === global); // true
        }
    }
};
obj.method();
```

Put another way: Your assertion is only true at global scope.

---

I say "the default `this`" above because the default `this` varies depending on whether you're in strict or loose mode. In strict mode, it's `undefined`. In loose mode, it's a reference to the global object.

---

> Isn't it effectivly just a special Method Inovcation.

Turn that on its head: JavaScript [doesn't have *methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html). It has *functions*, and ways of calling those functions which set `this` to various values. **One** of those ways sets `this` to refer to the object that the property with the function reference came from (e.g., `obj.foo()`).

Comment: Yes after tinkering I agree with you. in function position a function this param is always bound to global object. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

function f(){} is created within the scope, so it is really similar to method invocation.

so if you do that in the window space, it's actually window.f() that is created. So, you can access it via this.f(), when this points to current namespace which is window. if however you create a new function within other function, it would not be any more accessible directly via this, but you would have to get the reference to the object first.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have methods - only functions. Each function invocation has a context (`this`), which is (usually) decided at runtime rather than being an inherent property of the function.

"Method"-style invocation is no more or less than one way of invoking a function with an explicit `this`. The following invocations have exactly the same effect:

```
function f() { }
var o = { f: f }

o.f();
f.call(f);
o.f.call(f);
```

The fact that `f` *can* be called as a "method" of `o` has no special relevance to `f` or the ways it can be called.

Function application uses the *default* `this`, which is `undefined` in strict mode or the global object (`window` or `global`) otherwise.

N.B. it is possible to bake a specific `this` into a function using `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
var g = f.bind(o);
g(); // `this` is o, not the global object.
```